# what is the advantage in creating user profiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I noticed that many people create associated profiles to the main users of their site. What is the advantage of doing this?

Right now my app is set up to deal directly with the user for ALL of their attributes. Before I move forward I want to get some perspective on what the ideal path would be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective it really depends on what kind of application this and who the users are. Some use cases where you need a profile that does not have ALL the attributes

- The app administrator has control over items such as roles
- One user may want to be able to look at another users profie, but that may not want to have things such as salary, employee ID, email address exposed, and should not be able to change attributes.

So really depends on the app, its users, and what yoou are trying to do